# Processing embedded css in an html page with Gulp

Tags: html, css, node.js, prefix, gulp

I would like to use [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) for the embedded css within my html file.

I use jade and stylus for my nodejs project. Most of the css that I use are very small. Hence, I prefer to embed them into the jade files using stylus filter. Here's an example code.

```
style
  :stylus
    #container
      display: flex
```

I use [Gulpjs](http://gulpjs.com/) as my build tool. [gulp-autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-autoprefixer) works on `.css` files. How do I make it work for embedded style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-replace) plugin to replace embedded style within html files. Here's the snippet of my `gulpfile.coffee`

```
gulp.task 'autoprefix', ->
  gulp.src paths.html.source
    .pipe require('gulp-replace').replace /(<style>)((.|\n)*?)(<\/style>)/gm, (match, style_tag, prefixed)->
            style_tag + require('autoprefixer')('last 2 versions').process(String(prefixed)).css + "</style>"
    .pipe gulp.dest(paths.destination)
```

Would love to hear if there is more cleaner way to achieve the same.